# Integration by parts and notation.

Tags: integration, notation

I've just found that I must be missing something about the integral notation when it comes to the integration by parts.

First, $\int_a^b \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is perfectly clear: $\mathrm{d}x$ is an infinitely small difference; it also syntactically designates the variable of the integration. 
Meanwhile, it's not a purely syntactic thing, since you can, e.g. substitute variables which involves meaningful operations with $\mathrm{d}x$ and you see $f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ as a differential.

Now, consider the integration-by-parts formula:

$$\int_a^bu(x)v'(x)\mathrm{d}x = uv |_a^b - \int_a^bv(x)u'(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

The thing is, that it's commonly written as:

$$\int_a^bu\mathrm{d}v = uv |_a^b - \int_a^bv\mathrm{d}u$$

Now, what I don't understand, is the strict meaning of $\mathrm{d}v$ on the left and $\mathrm{d}u$ on the right. Those don't designate the variable of the integration, since the ranges of the integration have not changed, and $u$ and $v$ are still functions of $x$. So, is that only some convenience trick and we're saying something like "*yes, we know that it's not exactly correct, but as long as we know what we're doing it's ok*", or there is some deeper non-syntactic meaning in replacing $\int_a^buv'\mathrm{d}x$ with $\int_a^bu\mathrm{d}v$?

Comment: Good catch! It's one of many examples of [abuses of notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation) that litter introductory calculus. Its pretty much just compact shorthand that's easier to remember and quicker to write. (That said, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties_and_relation_to_the_Riemann_integral).

Comment: You have the prime on the wrong function on one side of the by-parts formula. On a higher level, the differential form $dv$ is $v'(x)\,dx$, ditto $u'(x)\,dx = du$. Up to a rearrangement, the integration-by-parts formula is just the product rule, $(uv)'(x)\,dx = d(uv) = u\,dv + v\,du = (u(x)v'(x)+ u'(x)v(x))\,dx$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks, fixed the order.

Comment: @DavidH, wow, that really sheds some light. Apparently, given that it's clear that $u$ and $v$ are the functions of $x$ and $u'$ and $v'$ are continuous, we can write it that way, just with a bit more advanced definition of integral. Thanks! (Please add an answer if you want me to accept it).

Answer (score -1):

If you check the calculus text you are reading it should explain that $u$, $du$, $v$ and $dv$ are defined to be $u=f(x)$, $du = f'(x)dx$, $v = g(x)$ and $dv = g'(x)dx$ (or any letters of your choice). Mathematicians are famously lazy and hide all sorts of pedantic notation in other simpler notation so they can spend their day doing math.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  I appreciate that you've picked an older "unanswered" Question for your post, but if you want to use mathematical notation here, it is possible with `MathJax` and $\LaTeX$ syntax.  See [this brief introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).